# unable to pass numpy ndarray to c program in python

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, ctypes

I am trying to pass a numpy nd array to a function but I am getting Type error.

Python code -

```
distancelib.distance.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_int, c_int, c_void_p, c_int];
dist = distancelib.distance(arr1.tolist(), arr2.tolist(), size[0], size[1], colorCodes, baseColor);
```

C Code -

```
double distance(float *arr1, float *arr2, int r, int c, int *colorCodes, int baseColor);
```

**arr1 and arr2 are images read using pil library.**

Error:

```
 dist = distancelib.distance(arr1.tolist(), arr2.tolist(), size[0], size[1], colorCodes, baseColor);
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Comment: well i mean you are passing it a list and it is expecting c_void_p so I can understand why you'd get a TypeError.  Could you post the error?

Comment: If you're just using `c_void_p` in `argtypes` then it's as simple as passing `arr1.ctypes`, for which `arr1.ctypes._as_parameter_` is the array base address as a `c_void_p`.

Comment: @ballsdotballs, i have place the error message

Comment: this explains how to get ctypes data from ndarrays: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html

Comment: Great this worked thanks a lot

Comment: Note that the documentation has a weird mistake. It says "calling `self._as_parameter_`", but the `_as_parameter_` attribute is a property that returns a `c_void_p`. It doesn't get *called*. You simply pass `arr1.ctypes`. The ctypes function checks for the `_as_parameter_` hook.